# How to set a VBA variable to a cell object instead of the cell contents?

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I have loop where I work with different cells. As part of this loop I want to set cell color, however I am forced to use the full cell address instead of just a variable assigned. Below is a sample in one iteration of the loop.

Doesn't work with "Run-time error '424': Object required

```
ColorMe = SheetCheck.Cells(1, 1) 'ColorMe is the value in the Cell 1,1
ColorMe.Interior.Color = vbGreen
```

works

```
SheetCheck.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color = vbGreen
```

Comment: Use `Set ColorMe = ...`

Comment: You need to declare ColorMe as a range (Dim ColorMe as Excel.Range) and then use Set when assigning the range to ColorMe (Set ColorMe = SheetCheck.Cells(1,1))